# Issues with loading sonarqube dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

I installed latest sonarqube and server is running fine but when i go to localhost:9000/sonar i see below note any clue what this is ? don't see any issues logged in es/web/sonar logs

> SonarQube is under maintenance
>
> While waiting, you might want to investigate new plugins to extend the
>   current functionality.
>
> If you are an administrator and have no idea why this message is being
>   shown, you should read the upgrade guide.

Comment: Did you run the setup after upgrading? Read the [Setup Guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading).

Comment: Why are you opening http://localhost:9000/sonar? Default URL is without the "sonar" context - i.e. http://localhost:9000

Comment: Have you read the upgrade guide :) ?